# How can I extract each value from the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

How can I extract each value from the list?

```
[['f', 'Mina', 'C'], ['f', 'Sara', 'java'], ['m', 'Omid', 'C++'], ['m', 'Hooman', 'python']]
```

I want the output be like this:

```
f Mina C
f Sara java
m Omid C++
m Hooman python
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: It was written with python

Comment: What have you tried for yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I want to extract the list as I wrote in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_val =[['f', 'Mina', 'C'], ['f', 'Sara', 'java'], ['m', 'Omid', 'C++'], ['m', 
'Hooman', 'python']]

for j in  (list_val):
    print (j[0],j[1],j[2])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
name_list =[['f', 'Mina', 'C'], ['f', 'Sara', 'java'], ['m', 'Omid', 'C++'], ['m', 
'Hooman', 'python']]
for names in name_list:
    print(names)
```

remember to assign `name_list` variable for list

Comment: This is somewhat inconsistent. Did you mean `for names in name_list`? But even then it will print tuples with brackets and commas.

Comment: he can slice tuple and commas, but  if he use list name and give print by index then good for small list but what if have more than thousand entry in list

Comment: About print: I'd suggest using `print(*names)` so it prints the different _parts_ of the tuples in one line, and not the tuple itself.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is one method of getting the result you want.

```
list = ['f', 'Mina', 'C'], ['f', 'Sara', 'java'], ['m', 'Omid', 'C++'], 
['m', 'Hooman', 'python']


for i in list:
  print(i)
```

The output of the code will be:

```
['f', 'Mina', 'C']
['f', 'Sara', 'java']
['m', 'Omid', 'C++']
['m', 'Hooman', 'python']
```